# Fable 2 End-Game Achievements

Tags: achievements, fable-2, xbox-360

Is it possible to get the three Xbox achievements:

- The Sacrifice -25g - Choose "The needs of the many"
- The Family -25g - Choose "The needs of the few"
- The Egomaniac -25g - Choose "The needs of the one"

without playing the entire game three times?

It seems as though the autosave feature prevents you from doing anything tricky here. Is there are way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, safe the game in a different slot before you take your decision. Now you can easily get all three achievements.

Answer (score 2):

You can also hit the guide button and exit to dashboard as soon as the achievement pops.  Then just reload your save and choose a different ending.  That's how I got mine!